# "Rainbow of color" or "Rainbow of colors."

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

While editing a text, I came across this sentence: **"The festival is a rainbow of color and joy."**

My question concerns the word "**color**."  I feel it should be plural: "The festival is a rainbow of color**s** and joy."

I asked a colleague and she felt it was fine because color was describing the rainbow...an adjective use.  I felt that a rainbow cannot be only one color and consists of many so it should be "colors."

Color or colors?  Is there a way to decide this?

I should point out that the context is an article about a festival in which people dress up with multi-colored costumes.

Comment: The festival is a rainbow of ***color and joy***  - ***colour***: *the pleasant effect of a bright colour or of a lot of colours together*.http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/colour

Comment: It's an awkward expression anyway. A *rainbow of color* is an antonym of a *rainbow of black-and-white*.

Comment: "The festival is a *symphony* of color and joy." Notice how using a different metaphor removes it from the literal (and limited) spectrum of sunlight being refracted by droplets of water in the air. Most festivals are **much** more colorful than rainbows. :-) Extra credit for *a rainbow of black-and-white.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the rainbow above is a spectrum of colors, the word **rainbow** here is a metaphor for an abundance of good things such as the beauty of **color** and the delight of **joy**. The festival is filled with color and joy.

If it were an actual rainbow, we would not need to hear there were colors, as we would know that.

[American Heritage (5th Edition) definition:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rainbow)

> A diverse assortment or collection.

Compare the phrasing from the Shaker hymn Simple Gifts:

> In the valley of love and delight

Why would we want to be in a valley with only one delight instead of a cornucopia of them? We would not, but the *delight* is the valley's specialty, and it has its generous share.

Comment: But if I replace "rainbow" with "collection" the sentence seems not to work: "...a collection of color and joy."  Seems like we should have a collection of things, "colors."  I understand the metaphor aspect.  Could it be that even if it's a metaphor, the grammar needs to match?  Maybe I'm getting confused because color can be a countable and non-countable noun.

Comment: Collection is not wrong but not poetic, either. Try _is a generosity (or array, or smorgazbord) of color_. It _is rich with color_. No plural needed inside the prepositional phrase -> My garden is filled with color, and they have gardens of color.